# Send pattern to a function

Tags: javascript, regex, input

I have a personal function who take an id and a pattern for check some input.

```js
var id, schema;
 function checkField(id, schema){
  var input = id.val();
  var pattern = schema;

  if (!input.match(pattern)){
   console.log('Input = '+input);
   console.log('Pattern = '+pattern);
   id.removeClass().addClass("error");
   $(".oke").css({display: 'none'});
  }else{
   console.log('Classe = ok');
   id.removeClass().addClass("ok");
   $(".nope").css({display: 'none'});
  }
 }

 // Vérification téléphone
 $("#tel").focusout(function(){
  checkField($(this), "/0[1-7,9]\d{8}/");
 });

 // Vérification code postale
 $("#cp").focusout(function(){
  checkField($(this), "/^((0[1-9])|([1-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])|(2A)|(2B))[0-9]{3}$/");
 });
```

But the if condition always return `null` (`!input.match(pattern)`).
The two console log return the number write in input, and the pattern correctly, why the if is always false ?

Comment: The double quotes must be removed from around regexps and the first one might also need anchors (`/^0[1-79]\d{8}$/`). And the second one can be written as `/^(0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-8]|2[AB])\d{3}$/`. Also, it is advisable to replace `if (!input.match(pattern))` with `if (!pattern.test(input))`

Comment: Excellent, thanks :)

What is the difference between input.match pattern and pattern.test input ?

Comment: `test()` returns *true* or *false* while `match` will either return *null* or an array of match data.

Comment: Juste pour info,il me semble que `2A` et `2B` ne sont utilisés que pour le département, dans les codes postaux pour la Corse on utilise `20xxx` et non `2Axxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `"/0[1-7,9]\d{8}/"` to the `String#match()`, the single `\` before `d` is removed as it is an unknown escape sequence and the `/` around the pattern are treated as literal `/` symbols in the pattern. Thus, you get no matches. Also, the `,` in the character class is also considered a literal comma, I am sure you want to remove it from the pattern. Besides, the first pattern lacks `^` at the start and `$` anchor at the end if you plan to match the entire string. Either pass `"^0[1-79]\\d{8}$"` or  - preferred - use a regex literal `/^0[1-7,9]\d{8}$/` (no double quotes around the pattern).

The second pattern can be shortened as `/^(0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-8]|2[AB])\d{3}$/` - again, note the absence of the double quotes around the regex literal notation.

Also, it is advisable to replace `if (!input.match(pattern))` with `if (!pattern.test(input))` as `regex.test(str)` returns *true* or *false* while `str.match(regex)` will either return *null* or an array of match data.

So, what you can use is

```
if (!pattern.test(input)){
...

$("#tel").focusout(function(){
    checkField($(this), /^0[1-79]\d{8}$/);
});

$("#cp").focusout(function(){
    checkField($(this), /^(0[1-9]|[1-8]\d|9[0-8]|2[AB])\d{3}$/);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript regex patterns are **not strings**, you should remove the double quotes.

```
$("#tel").focusout(function(){
    checkField($(this), /0[1-7,9]\d{8}/);
});

$("#cp").focusout(function(){
    checkField($(this), /^((0[1-9])|([1-8][0-9])|(9[0-8])|(2A)|(2B))[0-9]{3}$/);
})
```